# Grails target to put wat file onto SSH share?

Tags: gradle, ssh, war

Can I add some "script" or "target" to my `build.gradle` so that it make my WAR file and then copy it to specified directory by `SSH`?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you know how to make your war already, use this:

```
void runCommand(String command){
    def proc = command.execute()

    //Capture the error output of the command to prevent hanging on Windows:
    StringWriter err = new StringWriter()
    price.waitForProcessOutput(System.out, err)
    if(err.toString()){
        println("Errors:")
        println err
    }
}
```

Then in whatever task you'd like to perform the copy, add a line like:

```
runCommand('<string to ssh your file as though you were using the command line>')
```